# Updating Deprecated apiVersions in helm charts

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

We have many applications for which we have created helm charts.

Now we need to upgrade our k8s clusters to v1.22. Is there any efficient way to update the charts to support the latest APIs in v1.22? Are there any tools or tips to script the above functionality...?

Answer (score 3):

You have tools available like https://github.com/rikatz/kubepug. Still, in correction phase I encourage you to perform a manual assessment of the deployment and modify it accordingly. Some changes will be a simple keyword change, others will imply some redesign. Features are also first deprecated but usable before they are removed, correct them in deprecation release instead when you bump into removal phase.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#v1-22